# Why the table floats over the margins and seems not to be centered?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{flafter}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm
 }

\usepackage{tgtermes}
%\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage{enumerate,mdwlist}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.69,1.21,1.21}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\linespread{1.3}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname{Table of Contents}}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\sffamily}

\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}




\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{r r r r r r }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{LightCyan}

    \thead{Current \textit{I}/ \si{\milli\ampere} \\ $\Delta I$ $\approx$  0 \si{\milli\ampere}} & \thead{Voltage \textit{$V_{1}$}/ \si{\volt} \\ $\Delta$ $V_{1}$ = $\pm$  0.01 \si{\volt}}  & \thead{Voltage \textit{$V_{2}$}/ \si{\volt} \\ $\Delta$ $V_{2}$ = $\pm$  0.0001 \si{\volt}} &  \thead{Voltage $\frac{V_{1}}{V_{2}}$/ \si{\volt} \\ } & \thead{Fractional uncertainty\\$\frac{\Delta V_{1}}{V_{1}}$+$\frac{\Delta V_{2}}{V_{2}}$} & V1(V)  \bigstrut\\

    \hline
    1   & 0.50 & 0.5837 & 0.8566044 & 0.0202 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    2   & 1.00 & 1.1875 & 0.8421053 & 0.0101 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    3   & 1.50 & 1.7928 & 0.8366801 & 0.0067 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    4   & 2.00 & 2.4034 & 0.8321544 & 0.0050 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    5   & 2.50 & 3.0182 & 0.8283083 & 0.0040 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    6   & 3.00 & 3.6359 & 0.8251052 & 0.0034 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    7   & 3.50 & 4.2556 & 0.8224457 & 0.0029 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    8   & 4.00 & 4.8728 & 0.8208833 & 0.0025 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    9   & 4.50 & 5.4929 & 0.8192394 & 0.0022 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    10  & 5.00 & 6.1217 & 0.8167666 & 0.0020 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    11  & 5.50 & 6.7480 & 0.8150563 & 0.0018 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    12  & 6.00 & 7.3694 & 0.8141775 & 0.0017 & 0.7500 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: your headings are just too wide to fit the page, you need to make them narrower, perhaps fractional uncertainty add `\\ ` to make it an extra line, or use a smaller font or ...

Answer (score 5):

[Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) overtake me (again) for 48 seconds ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.69,1.21,1.21}
%\usepackage{xcolor, colortbl}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{flafter}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{tc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm
 }
\usepackage{tgtermes}
%\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,textcomp}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{enumerate,mdwlist}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\linespread{1.3}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname{Table of Contents}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                                 S[table-format=2]
                                 S[table-format=1.2]
                                 S[table-format=1.4]
                                 S[table-format=1.6]
                            *{2}{S[table-format=1.4]}
                                }
    \toprule
{\thead{$I$/\si{\milli\ampere}\\ $\Delta I\approx 0$ \si{\milli\ampere}}}
    & {\thead{$V_{1}$/\si{\volt}\\ $\Delta V_{1} = \SI{\pm 0.01}{\volt}$}}
        & {\thead{$V_{2}$/\si{\volt}\\ $\Delta V_{2} = \SI{\pm e-4}{\volt}$}}
            & {\thead{$\frac{V_{1}}{V_{2}}$/\si{\volt}}}
                & {\thead{Fractional\\[-1ex] uncertainty\\
                         $\frac{\Delta V_{1}}{V_{1}}+\frac{\Delta V_{2}}{V_{2}}$}}
                    & {$V_1(V)$}     \\
    \midrule
    1   & 0.50 & 0.5837 & 0.8566044 & 0.0202 & 0.7500 \\
    2   & 1.00 & 1.1875 & 0.8421053 & 0.0101 & 0.7500 \\
    3   & 1.50 & 1.7928 & 0.8366801 & 0.0067 & 0.7500 \\
    4   & 2.00 & 2.4034 & 0.8321544 & 0.0050 & 0.7500 \\
    5   & 2.50 & 3.0182 & 0.8283083 & 0.0040 & 0.7500 \\
    6   & 3.00 & 3.6359 & 0.8251052 & 0.0034 & 0.7500 \\
    7   & 3.50 & 4.2556 & 0.8224457 & 0.0029 & 0.7500 \\
    8   & 4.00 & 4.8728 & 0.8208833 & 0.0025 & 0.7500 \\
    9   & 4.50 & 5.4929 & 0.8192394 & 0.0022 & 0.7500 \\
    10  & 5.00 & 6.1217 & 0.8167666 & 0.0020 & 0.7500 \\
    11  & 5.50 & 6.7480 & 0.8150563 & 0.0018 & 0.7500 \\
    12  & 6.00 & 7.3694 & 0.8141775 & 0.0017 & 0.7500 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}%
  \end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

in your preamble you load some packages twice .. i comment them in above mwe. I also correct settings for `makecell` others is more or less the same as  as at [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) answer.

Comment: +1. Since the code features the instruction `\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}`, the instruction `\usepackage{color, colortbl}` could (and, in fact, should) be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, you need to make some of the header cells less wide -- ideally, by inserting a couple of line breaks in columns 4 and 5.

I would also simplify and streamline the entire look of the table, mostly by getting rid of all `\hline` directives and using, in their place, `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\addlinespace` (2 instances), and `\bottomrule`. That'll also let you get rid of all `\bigstrut` directives.

Showing the voltage ratios with 7 [!] significant digits seems like overkill. I suggest you enlist some of the capabilities of the `siunitx` package to round the figures to just 3 places. It also seems pointless to show 4 digits in the final column, when 2 digits will do just fine.

Separately, I have to express an opinion that adding color to the header material does exactly nothing for its legibility or for the readability of the table as a whole. I wouldn't use colors, honestly, unless I wanted to create an appearance of gaudiness. Finally, I've maintained your setting of rendering text-mode words in the header cells in sans-serif, but I must confess I don't think it adds much (if anything...).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%% (simplified the preamble as much as possible)
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,float}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={170mm,257mm},margin=20mm}

\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadalign{tc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\sffamily}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[2pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[2pt]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
    \sisetup{detect-mode,round-mode=places}
    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc
                       S[table-format=1.3,
                         round-precision=3]
                       c
                       S[table-format=1.2,
                         round-precision=2]@{}}
    \toprule
    \thead{Current $I$ (\si{\milli\ampere}) \\ 
    $\Delta I \approx \SI{0}{\milli\ampere}$} 
  & \thead{Voltage $V_{1}$ (\si{\volt}) \\ 
    $\Delta V_{1}  = \pm \SI{0.01}{\volt}$}  
  & \thead{Voltage $V_{2}$ (\si{\volt}) \\ 
    $\Delta V_{2} = \pm \SI{0.0001}{\volt}$} 
  & {\thead{Voltage\\ratio \\ 
    $V_{1}/V_{2}$}}
  & \thead{Fractional\\uncertainty\\
    $\frac{\Delta V_{1}}{V_{1}}+\frac{\Delta V_{2}}{V_{2}}$} 
  & {\textsf{V1} (\si{V})} \\
    \midrule
    1   & 0.50 & 0.5837 & 0.8566044 & 0.0202 & 0.7500 \\
    2   & 1.00 & 1.1875 & 0.8421053 & 0.0101 & 0.7500 \\
    3   & 1.50 & 1.7928 & 0.8366801 & 0.0067 & 0.7500 \\
    4   & 2.00 & 2.4034 & 0.8321544 & 0.0050 & 0.7500 \\
    \addlinespace
    5   & 2.50 & 3.0182 & 0.8283083 & 0.0040 & 0.7500 \\
    6   & 3.00 & 3.6359 & 0.8251052 & 0.0034 & 0.7500 \\
    7   & 3.50 & 4.2556 & 0.8224457 & 0.0029 & 0.7500 \\
    8   & 4.00 & 4.8728 & 0.8208833 & 0.0025 & 0.7500 \\
    \addlinespace
    9   & 4.50 & 5.4929 & 0.8192394 & 0.0022 & 0.7500 \\ 
    10  & 5.00 & 6.1217 & 0.8167666 & 0.0020 & 0.7500 \\
    11  & 5.50 & 6.7480 & 0.8150563 & 0.0018 & 0.7500 \\
    12  & 6.00 & 7.3694 & 0.8141775 & 0.0017 & 0.7500 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution, with improvement and code simplifications, using systematically `siunitx` and `makecell`(in particular rules with variable thickness), and replacing the `\bigstrut` commands with the `cellspace` package, which defines *minimal* vertical spacing at top and bottom of cells in columns prefixed with the letter `S`, or `C` if, as is the case here, you load `siunitx`. Note the padding commands from `makecell` seem to have problems with table colour commands. Also, I loaded `caption` to have a sensible spacing between caption and table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{caption, float}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 hmargin=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 showframe
 }

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, textcomp}%
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage[EULERGREEK]{sansmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage{enumerate,mdwlist}

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.69,1.21,1.21}

\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\linespread{1.3}
%\renewcommand{\contentsname{Table of Contents}}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\sffamily\sansmath}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

%\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
% \renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering\sisetup{detect-all}

    \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{Cr r r r r r }
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    \rowcolor{LightCyan}

    \thead{Current $I/ \si{\mA}$ \\ $\Delta I\approx \SI{0}{\mA}$} & \thead{Voltage $V_{1}/\mkern1.5mu \si{\V}$ \\ $\Delta V_{1} = \pm \SI{0.01}{\V}$} & \thead{Voltage $V_{2}/\mkern1.5mu \si{\V}$ \\ $\Delta V_{2} = \pm \SI{0.0001}{\V}$} & \thead{Voltage $\frac{V_{1}}{V_{2}}/ \mkern1.5mu\si{\V}$} & \thead{Fractional\\[-1ex] uncertainty\\[-0.5ex] $\frac{\Delta V_{1}}{V_{1}} + \frac{\Delta V_{2}}{V_{2}}$} & V1(V) \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    1 & 0.50 & 0.5837 & 0.8566044 & 0.0202 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    2 & 1.00 & 1.1875 & 0.8421053 & 0.0101 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    3 & 1.50 & 1.7928 & 0.8366801 & 0.0067 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    4 & 2.00 & 2.4034 & 0.8321544 & 0.0050 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    5 & 2.50 & 3.0182 & 0.8283083 & 0.0040 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    6 & 3.00 & 3.6359 & 0.8251052 & 0.0034 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    7 & 3.50 & 4.2556 & 0.8224457 & 0.0029 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    8 & 4.00 & 4.8728 & 0.8208833 & 0.0025 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    9 & 4.50 & 5.4929 & 0.8192394 & 0.0022 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    10 & 5.00 & 6.1217 & 0.8167666 & 0.0020 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    11 & 5.50 & 6.7480 & 0.8150563 & 0.0018 & 0.7500 \\
    \hline
    12 & 6.00 & 7.3694 & 0.8141775 & 0.0017 & 0.7500 \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    \end{tabular}%
  \end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]